# Evaluation error: column 1 must be named

Tags: r, r-haven

I am getting the following error when reading a column from sas data in R

```
library(haven)
Sas_temp=read_sas("My_sas_file.sas7bdat",cols_only="Bth_dt")
```

This produces the error

```
Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data,spec_cat,encoding=encoding,cols_only=cols_only):

Evaluation error: Column 1 must be named.
```

This does not happen when I read another column. Is there anything which I am missing out here? how to resolve this?

Comment: Is `Bth_dt` definitely the name of the column in your SAS file?